# Web layout works in firefox but not chrome or any other broswer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have a really strage issue.

My website design works fine in firefox.

but any other browser it doesnt work. even chrome.

any ideas on whats going on?

webpage in question: http://woffal.com/profile.php/?u=tyleroakley

thanks,

daniel

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="na" style=" width:100%; height:250px; margin-top:150px;">
```

Just remove `height:250px;` on the element. A child element doesn't stretch, so does its container. Look at your `wrapper` div, it stays the same as `na` div is set to `height:250px;` Child's content affects the wrapper's size only, as long as there's no specific demansion property given on it.

Displaying well on Firefox is a strange one in this case.